# Jira/Subversion/CruiseControl release notes, migrate to bamboo?

Tags: c#, svn, jira, cruisecontrol.net, bamboo

We are using a combination of Jira, Subversion and CruiseControl.net in our workflow. With each commit, the corresponding Issue-ID is stored in a bugtraq-property of svn. Jira accesses the repository via plugin (not FishEye at the moment), and a custom svn hook updates the Jira-Issue with the branch name. So each issue is linked to all branches it relates to. Also, release notes for each issue are stored in custom fields, as we need the release notes in multiple languages.
CruiseControl runs builds on schedule, with increasingly complex build scripts to integrate the release notes into our application. As some of the branches are custom userware, only a subset of the release notes are actually used (requirements of one customer should not neccessarily be visible to other customers, whereas the customer information is generated from the branch names). I've spent quite some time on the web looking for plugins to interface Jira and CruiseControl with eachother to better automate this process. Is there anyone out there with similar problems?

Would a migration to Jira/Bamboo/FishEye solve my problem? I've downloaded the test versions and dabbled around with the tool integration, but I'm really looking for constructive advice and experience reports. The ability to start builds from within Jira certainly looks appealing, and FishEye should provide branch information to Bamboo.
I hope, I'm making sense here...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to scale a product build when it's a different build for each customer. And a branch per customer soon becomes hard to do all the merging needed.

Comment: JIRA and Bamboo will help to some degree but I'd recommend looking at the whole approach again

Answer (score 0):

Jira and Bamboo are obviously better integrated. SVN hooks to Jira are better than Fisheye smart commits. The only other CI product with this level of integration with Jira is Jenkins via marvelution plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.marvelution.jira.plugins.jenkins

Our shop is a lot of Java developers, a few MS devs. Java developers mainly use a SVN/Jira/Fisheye/Jenkins combo with release notes generated automatically via Jira and Jenkins. The MS developers use TFS for their projects.

You could always bite the Microsoft bullet and use TFS 2012.

So besides the ITIL-breaking release management snieps in the question comemnts, the answer is Jira/(Jenkins|Bamboo) will solve your problem. Fisheye is just a nice to have.